# React Native Debugger - CORB

Tags: google-chrome, react-native, cross-origin-read-blocking

A Chrome update has happened and now I can not debug my React Native network requests via the Chrome browser as they are being blocked by CORB (not CORS).

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://example.com/my/url with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Request Headers

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
...
```

Response Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,x-goog-authuser
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
```

Comment: The Access-Control-Allow-\* headers have no effect on CORB behavior. The reason Chrome is blocking the read is because the resource is being served with an application/json MIME type but your frontend is trying to consume the response in some way the browser doesn’t expect an application/json resource to be consumed.

Comment: It is being consumed using `https://github.com/axios/axios ` inside React Native. But I am using Chrome to debug the network connections using `GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest || GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest`